# OpenGL/VB.Net/OpenTK camera rotation

Tags: vb.net, opengl, opentk

I'm trying some basic openGL stuff, using the openTK library and writing in vb.net. I can get a triangle on the screen but the co-ordinates have to be within +/- 1.

I understand that this is because of clipping, and so I need a bunch of matrix maths to setup a camera and perspective.

I use the openTK library routines to build the matrixes but I just get a blank window. I've stripped down my code to what I think is the bare minimum, and I've got it down to one line that I can comment in and out to break it or make it work.

I'm clearly missing something obvious, but I'm not sure what. Help?

```
Private Sub DrawFrame()
    Dim VertexArray() As Double = {0.0, 0.5, 0.0, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, -0.5, 0.0}
    Dim ratio As Single = Width / Height
    Dim ProjCameraModelHandle As Int32 = GL.GetUniformLocation(ProgramID, "u_mvp")
    Dim ProjCameraModelMatrix As Matrix4 = Matrix4.Identity
    Dim Eye, Target, Up As Vector3
    GL.UseProgram(ProgramID)

    Eye = New Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 4.0)
    Target = New Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    Up = New Vector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

    ModelMatrix = Matrix4.Identity
    CameraMatrix = Matrix4.LookAt(Eye, Target, Up)
    ProjMatrix = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(Math.PI / 4, ratio, 1, 1000)

    CameraModelMatrix = CameraMatrix * ModelMatrix

    ' Commenting out this line shows the triangle as expected
    ProjCameraModelMatrix = ProjMatrix * CameraModelMatrix

    GL.UniformMatrix4(ProjCameraModelHandle, False, ProjCameraModelMatrix)
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Double, False, 0, VertexArray)
    GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 3)
End Sub
```

Vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 u_mvp;

attribute vec4 vPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position =u_mvp * vPosition;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

If its needed, here's the rest of the code:

```
Imports OpenTK
Imports OpenTK.Platform
Imports OpenTK.Graphics
Imports OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal


Public Class OpenGLTest

    Public ProgramID As Integer
    Public LoadedFlag As Boolean
    Public TriVertexBufferID, TriIndexBufferID As Integer

    Private ProjMatrix, CameraMatrix, ModelMatrix, CameraModelMatrix, ProjCameraModelMatrix As Matrix4

    Private Function LoadShader(ByVal ShaderSrc As String, ByVal ShaderType As OpenGL.ShaderType)
    Dim ShaderID As Integer
    Dim IsCompiled As Integer
    Dim InfoLog As String

    ShaderID = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType)
    GL.ShaderSource(ShaderID, ShaderSrc)
    GL.CompileShader(ShaderID)
    GL.GetShader(ShaderID, ShaderParameter.CompileStatus, IsCompiled)
    If IsCompiled = False Then
        InfoLog = GL.GetShaderInfoLog(ShaderID)
        Debug.Print(InfoLog)
        GL.DeleteShader(ShaderID)
    End If

    Return ShaderID
    End Function

    Private Function LoadProgram() As Integer
    Dim VertexShaderStr, FragmentShaderStr As String
    Dim VertexShaderID, FragmentShaderID As Integer
    Dim ProgramID, IsLinked As Integer
    Dim InfoLog As String
    Dim Filename As String

    Filename = "vertex.shr"
    VertexShaderStr = File.ReadAllText(Filename)

    Filename = "fragment.shr"
    FragmentShaderStr = File.ReadAllText(Filename)

    VertexShaderID = LoadShader(VertexShaderStr, OpenGL.ShaderType.VertexShader)
    FragmentShaderID = LoadShader(FragmentShaderStr, OpenGL.ShaderType.FragmentShader)

    ProgramID = GL.CreateProgram
    GL.AttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID)
    GL.AttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID)

    GL.BindAttribLocation(ProgramID, 0, "vPosition")

    GL.LinkProgram(ProgramID)

    GL.GetProgram(ProgramID, GetProgramParameterName.LinkStatus, IsLinked)
    If IsLinked = False Then
        InfoLog = GL.GetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID)
        Debug.Print(InfoLog)
        GL.DeleteProgram(ProgramID)
    End If

    Return ProgramID
    End Function

    Private Sub DrawFrame()
    Dim VertexArray() As Double = {0.0, 0.5, 0.0, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, -0.5, 0.0}
    Dim ratio As Single = Width / Height
    Dim ProjCameraModelHandle As Int32 = GL.GetUniformLocation(ProgramID, "u_mvp")
    Dim ProjCameraModelMatrix As Matrix4 = Matrix4.Identity
    Dim Eye, Target, Up As Vector3
    GL.UseProgram(ProgramID)

    Eye = New Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 4.0)
    Target = New Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    Up = New Vector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

    ModelMatrix = Matrix4.Identity
    CameraMatrix = Matrix4.LookAt(Eye, Target, Up)
    ProjMatrix = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(Math.PI / 4, ratio, 1, 1000)

    CameraModelMatrix = CameraMatrix * ModelMatrix
    ProjCameraModelMatrix = ProjMatrix * CameraModelMatrix

    GL.UniformMatrix4(ProjCameraModelHandle, False, ProjCameraModelMatrix)
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Double, False, 0, VertexArray)
    GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 3)
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenGLTest_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ProgramID = LoadProgram()
    LoadedFlag = True
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest)
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height)
    GlControl1.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GlControl1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles GlControl1.Paint
    If LoadedFlag = True Then
        Call DrawFrame()
        GlControl1.SwapBuffers()
    End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that openTK does Matrix maths the other way round compared to OpenGL.

Instead of

```
CameraModelMatrix = CameraMatrix * ModelMatrix
ProjCameraModelMatrix = ProjMatrix * CameraModelMatrix
```

I should have

```
CameraModelMatrix = ModelMatrix * CameraMatrix
ProjCameraModelMatrix = CameraModelMatrix * ProjMatrix
```

see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452241/opentk-matrix-transformations) for the explanation.

Sigh.